# Where can I find upanishad's verse in vedas?

Tags: vedas, upanishads

Upaniṣads are the part of vedas. Is it possible to find the verse of upanishad in vedas.

For example :

> Bṛhadāraṇyaka Upaniṣad
>
> > Chapter I > Section IV - The Creation and Its Cause
> >
> > > In the beginning, this (universe) was but the self (Virāj) of a human form. He reflected and found nothing else but himself. He first uttered, ‘I am he.’ Therefore he was called Aham (I). Hence, to this day, when a person is addressed, he first says, ‘It is I,’ and then says the other name that he may have. Because he was first and before this whole (band of aspirants) burnt all evils, therefore he is called Puruṣa. He who knows thus indeed burns one who wants to be (Virāj) before him. (1.4.1)

Can anyone give the same verse but from vedas. Like rigveda 1:4:1 (just an example).

**basically my question is "Where can I find upanishad's verse in vedas as it is a part of vedas"**

Comment: Upanishads don't have locations like RigVeda X.Y.Z etc.

Comment: If an Upanishadic verse can be referred to as RigVeda X.Y.Z or AtharvaVeda X.Y.Z then people wouldn't be doubting if Upanishads are really part of Vedas or not. But that can't be done.

Comment: @Rickross no I am asking for the reference from the vedas as upanishad is a part of vedas. They must in vedas like isha upanishad (Shukla Yajurveda chapter 40).like that.

Comment: That is an exception. Not all are directly from the Samhita portions to have a location like Rig VedaX.Y.Z

Comment: @Rickross so some Upanishads are not part of the Vedas.

Comment: Another Upanishad called the Tadeva Upanishad also is directly part of Shukla YajurVeda. It's location is Vajasaneyi Samhita Chapter 32. But the same can't be done for other Upanishads generally.

Comment: No I'm not saying that but all Upanishads (generally) can't be located as Rigveda X.Y.Z or as something similar.

Comment: Brihadaranyaka Upanishad is part of Shatapatha Brahmana of Shukla Yajur Veda.

Comment: @Rickross if upanishad can't be located in the Vedas, how can they be a part of the Vedas.

Comment: I don't know that @DarkKnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Samhita verses in Vedas. I will limited examples from this [blog](https://goldenreed-hiranyayavetasa.blogspot.com/2020/10/concordance-of-rg-veda-samhita-with.html) of Ram Abloh Ji a great Vedic Scholar. Please read his blog.

> I was Manu and the Sun. I am the wise Kakṣīvān Ṛṣi. I nurture the
> white bolt of lightning (or the Ṛṣi Kutsa). I am the ancient Kavi
> Uśanā. O people, look at me! (i.e. you can also become enlightened
> like me) (RV 4.26.1)
>
> Having realized this truth, the Ṛṣi Vāmadeva declared “I was Manu and
> the Sun” (Br Up 1.4.10)
>
> O Agni, lead us on the right path as you O Lord are omniscient.
> Destroy this stubborn sin from us, we bow to you profusely.(RV
> 1.189.1)
>
> O God Agni, lead us on to prosperity by a good path, judging all our
> deeds. Take away ugly sin from us. We shall say many prayers unto
> thee.(Isa Up 18)
>
> Two birds of beautiful feathers, very attached to each other, best
> friends, sit on the same tree. Of them, one eats a tasty fruit, and
> the other watches silently without eating(RV 1.164.20)
>
> Two birds of beautiful plumage, who are inseparable friends, reside on
> the self-same tree. Of these, one eats the fruits of the tree with
> relish while the other looks on without eating.(Svet Up 4.6)
>
> The Omniscient One (Jātavedā) is well-hidden in wood (or bodies) just
> as an embryo is well-hidden in the womb of the pregnant. Agni is to be
> worshipped everyday by the awakened (i.e. enlightened), offering human
> beings.(RV 3.29.2)
>
> The fire lodged in the aranis, as the foetus is well-borne by the
> pregnant woman fit to be worshipped every day by watchful offerers and
> other men. This verily is that.(Katha Up 2.1.8)
>
> The Universal Person has a thousand heads, a thousand eyes and a
> thousand feet. He envelops the earth all around but stays above it by
> a measure of ten fingers .( RV 10.90.1)
>
> That Infinite Being has a thousand heads, a thousand eyes and a thousand feet enveloping
> the whole universe on all sides. He exists beyond ten fingers.(Svet Up 3.14)
>
> The Universal Person is indeed all this, whatever was, and whatever
> will be. He is the Lord of Immortality, and he grows by food.(RV
> 10.90.2)
>
> That which is, that which was, and that which is yet to be - all this
> is nothing but this Infinite Being. Though He grows beyond His own
> nature into the form of the objective universe, He still remains the
> lord of immortality.(Svet Up 3.15)

Comment: You didn't understand the question if i'm right. He is asking that if Brihadaranyaka Upanishad is part of Veda (as they say) then what is the location of the given mantras in the form of Shukla Yajurveda X.Y.Z? (since Brihadaranyaka is linked to ShuklaYajurveda)

Comment: No @Rickross He said "Is it possible to find the verse of Upanishad in Vedas...For example "

Answer (score 1):

Here I am giving a couple of examples -

The entire Isha Upanishad (one of the principal Upanishads) is actually the 40th chapter of Yajurveda Sanhita (Shukla Yajurveda).

Siva Sankalpa Upanishad (one of the minor Upanishads) is also part of the Yajurveda Sanhita [Shukla Yajurveda] (Chapter 34, hymns 1-6).

**References:**
You can check it by yourself in the following books (or any other translations).

Yajurveda translated by Tulsi Ram.

Principal Upanisads by Sarvepalli Radhakrishnan

112 Upanishads translated by K. L. Joshi